# Rails Validation on update only if form field has value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

How to validate rails app on update only if the submitted form field has value?

It should not validate if the submitted form field is blank.

User.rb

```
validates_presence_of :search_card, on: :update

def search_card
    card = Card.find_by_barcode(self.barcode)
    if card.nil?
      errors.add(:invalid_card, ", Please provide another card")
    end
  end
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank

Comment: It doesn't work!!!!

Comment: Not even with four exclamation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

You should fire *search_card* method on *before_validation* callback, if *barcode* has been changed:

```
before_validation :search_card, on: :update, if: Proc.new { |u| u.barcode_changed? }
```

**Old answer** (wrong)

You should use *if* statement with *Proc*. Try this:

```
validates_presence_of :search_card, on: :update, if: Proc.new { |u| u.search_card.present? }
```

Comment: It didn't worked. My case is bit different. There is two form, one is to update the user profile and the other is to update the barcode only. Therefore when update request is to edit the user profile form it should update without the validation and when the update request is to update the barcode then it should validate with the above expression.

Comment: @SantoshAryal Sorry, my first answer is completely wrong. I've made some update, so you can try the new one.

Comment: thanks pan.goth i used your recommendation but it allowed to update the barcode without validating the barcode of Card model.

Comment: @SantoshAryal could you show me the part of your code after updating?

Answer (score 0):

You can use client side validations for it. For more details see `https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations`. Also, use `callback(before_create)` to validate the values.